# Spring Boot condition persisted in database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

ALL!

The question is as follows: is there any analogue of @ConditionalOnProperty, but persisted in the database, rather then in .properties file?

Or is there any other way to control execution of @Scheduled task? In general, i wanted to customize all execution properties via persisted values, stored within the database (enabled, fixedRate etc.)?

Thanx in advance!